# How to pass build.gradle directory to gradlew?

Tags: build, gradle

`./gradlew` can be run in the same directory as the `build.gradle` file, but how can I run `gradlew` (standard Gradle wrapper) from another directory? For Make, one can pass "`-C DIRECTORY`" to "Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.". Is there an equivalent parameter in Gradle?

Answer (score 91):

Just found it from [Appendix D. Gradle Command Line](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html).

The answer is `-p <your project directory>`, which defaults to the current directory.

Comment: This seems to work fine for the gradle command, but I am having difficulty using ./gradlew (the gradle wrapper) from a different directory.

Comment: thanks, somehow i overlooked this parameter. And yes, it does work for gradlew: ```code/android/gradlew -p code/android tasks``` produces my desired output...

Comment: Should be `-p=<your project directory>`

Comment: @shaka-b Doesn't need to be, no. I use `-p android` and it works fine. `android` is the subdirectory I want it to run in.